# gcp: testing an application which uses ndb (no module named `google.appengine`)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a GAE application in python3, which uses datastore ndb client libraries. Is there a way to test it locally or with dev_appserver.py ?

Namely, is there a way to satisfy the `google.appengine.ext.ndb` import locally or via some mock/shim layer? Maybe I'm missing a module in my requirements.txt, not sure which.

[`dev_appserver.py --application my_application app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/testing-and-deploying-your-app) fails. The local server starts, but then it can't bring up the application because it fails early on in the imports with `ImportError: No module named 'google.appengine'`.

In case this is a requirements issue, I currently have: `google-cloud-datastore==1.7.1` in my `requirements.txt` file. Working examples for python3 are hard to come by.

Answer (score 1):

The `google.appengine` module is baked into the first-generation Python (2.7) runtime. It's not available to install via `pip` or in the second-generation (3.7) runtime.

The only way to use it is by writing and deploying a first-generation App Engine app.

You might be interested in a Python 3 version of the `ndb` client library instead: https://github.com/googleapis/python-ndb

Comment: I initially chose the 3.7 route because it looked like it was supported ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-python3-libraries)). But it's not the first python3 hurdle I've hit so far, and I'm starting to question why it's even offered. Isn't the ndb client part of the `google-cloud-datastore` package for python3?

Comment: looks like ndb is not in the python37 runtime. i just need the core datastore stuff. I might be okay for now. `google-cloud-datastore` provides module `google.cloud`.

Comment: Yes, if you don't actually need `ndb`, you can just use the `google-cloud-datastore` package instead.